# How to dynamically create and manage Dialogflow agents?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I have a restaurant delivery system and I want to create a chatbot that can take orders from customers, for each restaurant. Should I try to create one single agent to handle each restaurant (couldn't find features that could somehow pull this off in the official documentation), or create one agent for each restaurant? In this case, how do I go about updating the agent in case the customer wants to change something in how the bot operates (changing the menu, for instance)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is not a single correct answer to your question. It will depend on how similar or different the final bot will operate in each of the restaurants:

**-Option 1:** `If the way in which the bot will operate in each business scenario is completely different:`

It is better to keep different agents that will be specialised according to their desired behaviour.

**-Option 2:** `If the agents will behave similar but you have foreseen that there will be some significant deviations in between the agents’ behaviour (for example one agent will operate in a luxury restaurant and is expected to talk in a more elegant way):`

I would suggest creating a primitive agent which will work as a pre-trained model and that will need to be fine-tuned according to each business use case. This way, you will be able to train the original agent with more examples and then, once you think the general performance is achieved, you can export your agent to a zip file and create as many copies as desired. You will need to work individually with these Dialogflow agents individually in order to boost their performance towards the desired use case.

**-Option 3:** `If the general functionalities of the agent are the same:`

You can approach the differences by writing custom code that will act as an intermediary [1](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/api-overview). For example, you might want to distinguish between the restaurants by matching an intent that will extract the name of the restaurant as an entity [2](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/entities-overview). Afterwards, your custom code will interact with the appropriate database that stores the Menu information for the desired restaurant. This approach is extendable to other changes such as, having different prices depending on the location of your restaurant. If you were to use any of the integrations listed in [3](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations), you can also use fulfillment [4](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-overview), this choice will also depend on your particular scenario.

**Summary:**

All in all, I would say that you need to judge how similar the expected behaviour will be in each restaurant and act accordingly. Nevertheless, the expected behaviour might be similar at the start of your project (using option 3) and then, once you have noticed some key improvements to be made, you can deviate to option 2 by creating replicates of your agent in order to fine-tune its successors towards different goals.